# How do I get comments count while fetching posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have two collections `Posts` an `comments`. I am storing comments with postID. I want to show comments count field when fetching all the posts data.
How do I achieve this?

```json
    // posts
    {
        postID: '123',
        title: 'abc'
    }

    // comments 
    {
         postID: '123',
         comments: [
            {
                commentID: 'comment123',
                comment: 'my Comment'
            }
         ]
    }

    // Looking for this
    {
        postID: '123',
        title: 'abc',
        commentCount: 1
    }
```

Comment: In a single aggregation pipeline you could `"$lookup"` the `"comments"` and even use a `"pipeline"` in the `"$lookup"` to just return `"$size": "$comments"`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs
I can see the comments with lookup. But getting error in count here.
{
        $lookup: {
            from: 'comments',
            localField: 'postID',
            foreignField: 'postID',
            as: 'comments',
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$comments',
    },
    { $project: { comments_count: { $size: '$comments' } } },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "localField": "postID",
      "foreignField": "postID",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "commentCount": {"$size": "$comments"}
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "commentCount"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "postID": 1,
      "title": 1,
      "commentCount": {"$first": "$commentCount.commentCount"}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r1uGSFm3thd).

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
pipeline = [{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "comments",
        "let": {
            "postId": "$postId",
        },
        "pipeline": [
            {
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$eq": ["$postId", "$$postId"]
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$postId",
                    "comments_count": {"$sum": 1}
                }
            }
        ],
        "as": "comments"
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "postId": 1,
        "title":1,
        "comments_count": "$comments.comments_count"
    }
}]

db.posts.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Is `"$eq": ["$postId", "$postId"]` missing a `$`?

Comment: When I try to use your pipeline on mongoplayground.net, an error is reported.  Feel free to use the configuration from the link in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73484222/1409374) if you want to see for yourself. Note that the OP used `"postID"` rather than `"postId"`.

Comment: Yes, Have edited the the query and added $$ in postId @rickhg12hs

Comment: I don't get the expected results when I try your pipeline on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VqOzKEx5D4p).